# Only 4:3 resolutions are accepted by CameraX's "setTargetResolution" or Camera2's "setDefaultBufferSize"

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, android-camerax

I'm trying to implement a camera preview. I first tried to do this with the Camera2 api. Until the preview itself was fine, but the log showed that the camera was being opened at 1280x960 resolution: "Starting camera: 1280x960 -> NV21" which is the 4:3 resolution of the emulator camera closer to 1280x720, and just cropping the view. Even with the latter of 1280x720 being one of those returned by "Characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)". I've done everything but every resolution I set, it ignores it and chooses the closest 4:3. I switched to CameraX, but the ".setTargetResolution" is giving the same problem, even though I followed the [google tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started?hl=pt-%20br). And it's not just on the emulator, I tested it on a real device and that happened too. I downloaded an app and changed the camera resolution and the log showed "Starting camera: 1280x720 -> NV21". That is, it is possible, but I'm not getting it.

I've already tested it on real devices, I've already switched from camera2 to cameraX, but even so, the camera continues to start only at 4:3 resolutions and cuts the view to 16:9

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.